# Read CSV file and output result depending on date

Tags: csv, date, vbscript

I have a CSV file with 2 columns

```
02/07/2018,Week A
09/07/2018,Week B
16/07/2018,Week A
23/07/2018,Week B
30/07/2018,Summer Break
```

How do I read this in to a VBScript and then find the current week and then display a message to display the text from the 2nd column?

For instance, if today is `19/07/2018`, the displayed message would be `Week A`.

Comment: Can you please format your question and make clear how the 2 columns in your csv are separated? Apart from that: Why VBScript? In most use cases I can think of VBScript has been superseded by something better.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *specific* problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: Apologies -  new to the site and I have seen similar questions where people have answered with snippets of code.

I have a working code in PHP but need something that will run in Windows.

What other language would suggest, which will allow me to run on a windows platform.

Comment: VBScript is one option, PowerShell another.

Answer (score 2):

Opted for powershell..... never realised how much can be done using powershell....

```
    #Get the Current Week
$today = Get-Date
$delta = $today.DayOfWeek.value__ - 1

#Import CSV
$CheckDate = $today.AddDays(-$delta).Date
$data = Import-Csv weeks.csv | 
    Where-Object {
        ($_."WeekDate" -as [DateTime]) -eq $CheckDate
    }

#Rename Wallpaper
if ($data.WeekAB -eq "Week A") {
  Copy-Item "\\server\netlogon\Wallpapers\Staff_WeekA.jpg" "\\server\netlogon\Wallpapers\Staff.jpg"
  Copy-Item "\\server\netlogon\Wallpapers\Student_WeekA.jpg" "\\server\netlogon\Wallpapers\Staff.jpg"
    Write-Host "Week A"
}
else {
Copy-Item "\\server\netlogon\Wallpapers\Staff_WeekB.jpg" "\\server\netlogon\Wallpapers\Staff.jpg"
  Copy-Item "\\server\netlogon\Wallpapers\Student_WeekB.jpg" "\\server\netlogon\Wallpapers\Staff.jpg"
  Write-Host "Week B"
}
```

This method allows me to set the wallpaper in stead of displaying a message.

Thanks for the Powershell pointer :-)